# how to open a file by its full path?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, window.open

I have a GridView which has following template field that holds the filename, when the user clicks the filename, I call window.open() to open the file. My question is I can only pass relative path to window.open(). I got an error if I use full path. Is there any way I can use full path to open a file? Thanks.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFile" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("FileName")%>' OnClick="lnkFile_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Added: The actual location of the file is defined in web.config.

I have wrote following lnkFile_Click(). The old part will open a new window for the file, but I cannot pass fullpath of the file. The new part will let you have a choice to open or save the file. My question is, will this cause security issue?

```
protected void lnkFile_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SPRAttachmentLocation"] + "\\SPR" + sprID + "\\" + ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Exception ex = new Exception("Could not find the file, please contact your administrator.");
        Response.Write("<p align=\"center\"><br /><br /><br /><br />There has been an Error: <strong>" + ex.Message + "</strong></p>\n");

        return;
    }
```

New:

```
byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Old:

```
   string newWindowUrl = "/SPR_Upload/SPR" + sprID + "/" + ((LinkButton)sender).Text;

            string javaScript =
             "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
             "<!--\n" +
             "window.open('" + newWindowUrl + "');\n" +
             "// -->\n" +
             "</script>\n";

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", javaScript);
}
```

Comment: Does this file reside under the web site/application folder?  window.open() can only address something by URL - relative or absolute, where an absolute starts with "HTTP", "HTTPS", etc.

Comment: The actual location of the file is defined in the web.config. It could be either under the web site/application folder in a remote machine. So you  mean I cannot use window.open(). Is there any other function I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question gives the impression that you think that you can open a file from the user's local computer. If that's the case, this is not possible.

Window.open expects a URL because the file is located on the server side, not the client side.

With that said, if you are trying to open a file located on the server side and you know the full path to the file; what you need to do is generate the virtual path within your application where the file can be found. You do this by creating a Virtual Directory in your APP from the IIS Admin Manager (Control Panel-->Admin Tools -->IIS Mgmt) and mapping this directory to the actual physical directory.

**EDIT:**

Say for example your whole website is physically located on the server on `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\your_app`. Let's assume your app can be accessed via `http://example.com` and the files you want to serve are physically located on `d:\files`. Assume further that you  created a virtual directory for your app (as I explained above) and that you called this virtual folder `public_files`. If one knows the file name it should be possible to access the file by simply going to `http://example.com/public_files/filename.ext`. Since you in your app already know the file name, all you need to pass as parameter to window.open is this url (`http://example.com/public_files/filename.txt`)

Comment: @GaolaiPeng: check my edit. There's no much code to show. All the work is configuring the virtual directory on IIS for your APP.

Comment: If I use Reponse to view the file, will it cause security issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `use Response`? Do you mean streaming the file?

Comment: As long as you check that in fact the user should have permissions to access the file in question, there's no security issue. Note that your new approach DOES NOT require you to create a virtual directory as I explained on my answer. With your approach of streaming the file instead, you just need to make sure that a user cannot manipulate the link in a way that your program could blindly take the file name and stream it to the user w/o ensuring that its intended for him.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath.aspx) to get the virtual path to the file.

```
string vPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "/my/relative/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

if the file is not located within the virtual directory there are a number of security issues you need to consider and address. in general it's not a good idea to access a file outside of the virtual directory.

if you must, then you will need to raise security permissions and grant access to the file on the network.